# Kitty terminal: I don't have any colors on PS1 bash prompt

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, kitty

Unlike other terminal emulators with kitty terminals I have no colors on bash prompt.
I am using ubuntu, my PS1 is `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

What have I to setup for this?

Thanks

Comment: You start by checking if your terminal can manage ANSI escape sequences. Test with this command line: `echo -e "default text \0033[31m red text \0033[0m default text"`; If not, is there a way to modify the settings of the terminal?

Comment: It supports it, with your test I read `red text` in red, Another example: if I execute `ls -la` I get colored output in file lists. It's just the prompt that is not colored as in other terminal emulator (gnome terminal, terminator, etc)

Comment: Try with the following PS1 `\[\033[01;31m\]$(statstring)\[\033[00m\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$`; statstring is defined as a function in my `.bashrc`, I don't know if you have it.

Comment: it works, the prompt is colored now, can you explain it? maybe in an answer (I will accept it). I got the `statstring` warning/error but I read your edit, it is not a problem, I removed it from PS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work with the following code in your `~/.bashrc`

I don't know if you need to tamper with the variable `TERM`, but it is there in my
`~/.bashrc`. I borrowed it years ago, and don't know/remember what is actually necessary.

```
if [ "${TERM:0:5}" == "xterm" ]
then
 typeset TERM=xterm-color  # force colour prompt
fi

function statstring {
RC=$?
  if [ "0" != $RC ]; then
    printf "[$RC] "
  fi
}
case "$TERM" in
xterm-color)
#    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

    if [ "$USER" = root ]; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]$(statstring)\[\033[00m\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ '
    else
        PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]$(statstring)\[\033[00m\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ '
    fi
    ;;
*)
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    ;;
esac

if [ "$TERM" == "xterm-color" ]
then
 typeset TERM=xterm  # force basic prompt
fi
```

Explanation: ANSI escape sequences in PC computers start with ESC [ and in `echo` statements we can use \0033 (ASCII: 3*8+3 = 27 for ESC). See [**this link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for a detailed description of ANSI sequences.

There is also an 'error code message' when a command return with an error code. This is controlled by the function `statstring`.

[image]

Comment: It is still not clear why it needs this "tricks" to have color bash prompt unlike other terminal emulators.

Comment: This is a workaround with some extra features. I don't know your Kitty terminal and why it works differently from your other terminal emulators. Maybe it activates another alternative from your `.bashrc` file depending on the TERM setting or something like that.

Comment: I found the issue: my default `.bashrc` has this line: `case "$TERM" in xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;; esac ` (no newlines because is a comment). Kitty terminal is identified as `xterm-kitty` so I have to change the condition with `xterm-color|*-256color|xterm-kitty)` and it works.

Comment: I'm glad you found the cause of your problem. You did it yourself after a short discussion with me :-)

Comment: Yes, your last comment helped me to where to look for it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Kitty may not be recognised as a color terminal...
What is the `$TERM` environment variable set to?

In gnome-terminal it says:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

In kitty it says:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-kitty
```

Check your `.bashrc` for this line:

> ```
> xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
> ```

Add `xterm-kitty` to it, like this:

> ```
> xterm-color|*-256color|xterm-kitty) color_prompt=yes;;
> ```

Now restart kitty.